# How angular knows which service to inject?

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused with how Angular knows which service to inject. For example, suppose we create a logger service like that

```
appModule.factory('logger', function(){
    return { /* Logger module here */ };
});
```

Them, if in a certain controller I want to use this service, I know that I would use it like:

```
appModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, logger) { });
```

And this confuses me, because I'm not getting how Angular knows that `$scope` referes to the controller scope and `logger` refers to the logger service. It verifies the name os the variables? So that it tries to match the name of the variable with some service available?

If we were to add a third parameter `anotherParam` it would check for the service called `anotherParam`?

Comment: You seem to understand how to use it; you'd have to delve into the framework code to figure out the how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the injection is based on the name of the parameter, AngularJS uses what's generally referred to as introspection so it checks what the name of the parameters are in the function definition and then looks for services it has seen previously defined.

To explicitly keep these as strings so injection still works if you do minification (where the variable names are lost there's an alternative syntax)

```
appModule.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {}]);
```

^ in this way giving a list of the strings they will not be minified and angular can still determine how to appropriately do the injection.  Note that if you use this second method the order of the strings must match the order of parameters you expect to be injected and can be a gotcha if you accidentally add a string but no parameter or vice versa.  I believe there is a Grunt task that will take care of this for you (ng-min possibly not sure though)

Answer (score 3):

#### The magic is done by [**$injector.annotate**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector):

> **annotate(fn);**
>
> Returns an array of service names which the function is requesting for injection. This API is used by the injector to determine which services need to be injected into the function when the function is invoked. There are **three ways** in which the function can be annotated with the needed dependencies.

The first way is to extract the names of the arguments from the function signature:

> **Argument names**
>
> The simplest form is to extract the dependencies from the arguments of the function. This is done by converting the function into a string **using toString() method** and extracting the argument names.
>
> **Inference**
>
> In JavaScript calling toString() on a function returns the function definition. The definition can then be parsed and the function arguments can be extracted. NOTE: This does not work with minification, and obfuscation tools since these tools change the argument names.

From the source code , how $injector extracts arguments from a function:

```
if (fn.length) {
  fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
  forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg){
    arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name){
      $inject.push(name);
    });
  });
}
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/auto/injector.js#L77

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes.

To make it more clear, you can write

```
appModule.controller('MyController', ["$scope", "logger", function($scope, logger) { }]);
```

Then the magic angular use is, if you have a js function

```
var f = function(a, b, c, d) {};
console.log(f.toString());
// Output
// function (a, b, c, d) { [...] }
```

Angular still can get these info even you don't mention them manually.

See more http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di.